# Protected action defined in parent class not found during test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

My `Employer::ShiftsController` calls: `before_action :authenticate_request!`

```
class Employer::ShiftsController < Employer::ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_request!
  ...
end
```

which is defined in the parent, Employer::ApplicationController

```
class Employer::ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protected

    def authenticate_request!
       ...
    end

end
```

This API works when I send it data, but when I run our test:

```
class Employer::ShiftsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  test "index should return a list of shifts at a given date" do
    xhr :get, :index, date: '2015/9/8'

    assert_response :success
  end

end
```

I am getting an error:

```
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `authenticate_request!' for #<Employer::ShiftsController:0x007fa2dab0ff70>
```

Comment: It should work. Try remove `protected` temporarily. Is test working now?

Comment: I know right!? Removing protected doesn't fix it - I've temporarily moved a lot of the parent's content into the child, and that works.